# How can I get make to put the binaries in a different location?

Tags: directory, makefile, gnu-make

Short and easy question, but I seem to have a writer's block here:

Suppose I have a source code file in the same directory as the makefile I use to build the program:

```
confus@confusion:~/prog$ ls
binaries  includes  main.c  Makefile
```

How do I get make to put the binaries for my `main.c` in the `binaries` dir? Afterwards on a second run make should see if the binary file there is up to date (and don't compile it again) just like normal.

My thought was something like this:

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: all

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
TARGETS := $(subst %.c,binaries/%.o,$(SOURCES))

all:$(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS):$(SOURCES)
    ./compile "$(subst .o,.c,$(@F))" -o "$@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't say all targets depend on all sources, instead have a pattern rule

```
binaries/%.o: %.c
    ./compile ... -o $@ -c $<
```

you may also need to use a vpath

**Revised:** 
You also had a problem with your subst ...
this test worked (just for compiling individual .o files, you still need to link them, which would be a very simple rule)

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: all

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
TARGETS := $(patsubst %.c,binaries/%.o,$(SOURCES))

all:$(TARGETS)

binaries/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: That puts out the error: `No rule to make target `main.o', needed by `all'.  Stop.`

Comment: something is different in our environments because in mine the subst isn't doing the right thing ... y answer however is based on a working system (not using wildcard source selection though, its a practice I liek to  avoid) ... ill take a look however in a few hours

Comment: @con-f-use  what you showed in your paste is `Makefile:10: *** missing separator`  This just means that you need to replace the leading spaces with a <TAB> character.  I don't think that a <Tab> can be properly cut-n-pasted from a stackoverflow page (my tab was converted to spaces when I pasted it into my answer)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is strange. My editor is set to replace <Tab>s with spaces. I never had problems with make and that setting before.

Comment: @con-f-use Your editor probably knows NOT to replace leading tabs in makefiles, but when you pasted spaces - well it can only assume that you wanted them (the spaces came from stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @con-f-use let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2039/discussion-between-nhed-and-con-f-use)